# Cargar CSS según dispositivo con Bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un archivo `master.css` donde defino estilos generales y dos archivos más llamados `movilices.css` y `screen.css` que definen estilos específicos para cada dispositivo, ¿cómo puedo realizar la carga de estos archivos según el dispositivo usado utilizando Bootstrap?

Bootstrap trabaja los tamaños de dispositivos con iniciales md, xs, etc., la idea es cargar el CSS según estas mismas reglas, se que se puede hacer esto con clases en `div`s y elementos HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Por medio del atributo "media" del elemento "link" puedes hacerlo: Utiliza la misma sintaxis que media queries, de hecho es una de las formas de usarlas.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (width < 768px)" href="movilices.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (width > 768px)" href="screen.css" />
```

Answer (score 4):

No deberías diferenciar la carga de los .css segun el dispoistivo ya que para esto existe `media queries`

Dentro del mismo css puedes definir como aplica el estilo según el cambio de resolucion del dispositivo.

[Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[Uso de CSS3 Media Queries: consulta de Medios y responsive Design.](http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/css3-media-queries/)

De esta forma el css lo cargas siempre, pero si necesitas especializar algun estilo segun el tamaño del dipisitivo defines un `@media`

Comment: Sería ideal que copiaras la idea/ejemplo principal del enlace directamente en la pregunta. Si el enlace se rompe, esta respuesta quedaría incompleta

Comment: Pero si meto todos los estilos de todos los dispositivos (al menos 3) no obligaría al usuario a descargarse un único css con el peso de los 3 estilos ? en cambio si tengo distribuido el código separado solo recibiría el archivo master con los estilos generales y el archivo con los estilos específicos para su dispositivo ... menos peso del sitio no es mejor rendimiento ?

Comment: @CristoferFuentes es cierto lo que comentas, en realidad cuando propuse la respuesta estaba pensando mas en un desarrollo web responsive en donde en el browser el usuario puede cambiar dinamicamente el tamaño continuamente, con lo cual necesitas reacomodar el layout adaptables  a cada dimension en el momento. Si la dimension se determina cuando carga el dispositivo y luego no va a variaria no tendria sentido cargar estilo para resoluciones que nunca seran utilizadas, porque el dispositivo no permite al usuario cambiar de resolucion.