# ¿Cómo conseguir que no carguen ciertos elementos en la versión móvil de un sitio web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, programación-móvil

He probado con media queries y `display:none`, los elementos desaparecen pero revisando el Network del inspector veo que se cargan igual. La idea es ganar velocidad en los móviles quitando elementos pesados para acelerar la carga. Gracias.

Comment: Claro que se cargan igual, todo el `css` se procesa en el cliente y luego de la carga. media queries no son para ganar velocidad sino para **abaratar el desarrollo** multi-display. La otra opción es hacer sitios especializados para desktop y mobile, pero tiene muchos costos extra. La opción intermedia es esta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4048

Comment: dependiendo de la tecnologia que usas en el backend puedes determinar qué tipo de hojas de estilo procesar y qué vistas HTML mostrar. Qué utilizas en el lado del servidor?

Comment: Como dice @fredyfx, lo óptimo es determinar si el cliente (navegador) es `mobile` o `desktop` en el `backend`, es decir, antes de enviar datos.

Comment: Hola @agujex ¿Alguna respuesta te ayudó a solucionar tu problema?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, ninguna me convenció o algunas me parecieron muy complicadas para mi nivel. Lo que hice, fue [lo que publiqué en mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46527/1166). No la marqué como correcta porque no estoy seguro que sea lo más apropiado, pues aún no recibió ningún voto positivo.

Comment: Es probable que nadie la votara esa solución porque no funciona adecuadamente. Si te das cuenta sigue cargando todos los recursos (el reproductor de youtube) y, dependiendo de la velocidad del equipo o la conexión a internet, se cancelará la petición HTTP antes o después de solicitar otros recursos adicionales (imágenes, hojas de estilos, etc) que también serán cancelados.

Comment: @OscarGarcia En todas las pruebas que hice, lo único que comienza a cargarse es el iframe. Habría que ver si en conexiones más lentas se carga el `<video>`. Las imágenes no cargan porque así funciona el atributo `srcset` en `<picture>`. Al no hallar imagen en tamaño mobile no carga nada, en otros tamaños se carga la imagen asignada.

Answer (score 2):

Con `css` siempre aparecerá el contenido y después lo ocultara, por donde lo veas es mejor opción tener un sitio web exclusivo para móviles en este caso que solicitas para *"ganar mas velocidad en los móviles"*

> Una solución en Javascript es detectar el ancho de la pantalla y en en base a ese ancho hacer un redireccionamiento a tu sitio exclusivo para móviles, ***esto puede ser una solución no muy recomendada***
>
> este es un ejemplo con Javascript [obtenido de desarrollowe.com](http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/estilos-css-distintos-navegador-javascript.html)
>
> ```
> if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Firefox") { 
>     document.write("<LINK REL='stylesheet' HREF='estilo_firefox.css' TYPE='text/css'>"); 
> } 
> else 
> { 
>       if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer"){ 
>         if (BrowserDetect.version>=7){ 
>           document.write("<LINK REL='stylesheet' HREF='estilo_ie7.css' TYPE='text/css'>"); 
>         }else{ 
>           document.write("<LINK REL='stylesheet' HREF='estilo_ie6.css' TYPE='text/css'>"); 
>         } 
>       }else{ 
>           if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Opera"){ 
>             if (BrowserDetect.version<9){ 
>               document.write("<LINK REL='stylesheet' HREF='estilo_opera.css' TYPE='text/css'>"); 
>             }else{ 
>               document.write("<LINK REL='stylesheet' HREF='estilo_opera9.css' TYPE='text/css'>"); 
>             } 
>           }else{ 
>             document.write("<LINK REL='stylesheet' HREF='estilo_otros.css' TYPE='text/css'>"); 
>           } 
>       } 
> }
> ```

Otra forma es detectar del lado del servidor que tipo de navegador esta accediendo así evitas mandar al reenderizado de la página el contenido que no deseas ver, **nunca lo he intentado**.

He leído que con PHP usando la librería **php-browscap** para usarla con el siguiente código:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use phpbrowscapBrowscap;

$bc = new Browscap('cache');
/** @var stdClass $current_browser */
$current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();
```

ahora ya tienes un stdClass en $current_browser con toda la información disponible del browser.

Para tomar decisiones por cada navegador detectado puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
$curr_br = $current_browser->Browser;
$CoolBrowsers = $curr_br == 'Chrome' || $curr_br == 'Firefox';

if ($CoolBrowsers) {
  add_asset('css', 'just-for-cool-browsers.css');
  $output = renderAdvancedLayout();
}
else {
  add_asset('css', 'just-for-bad-bad-browsers.css');
  $output = renderBasicLayout();
}
```

También puedes detectar si están accediendo desde un móvil o una tablet, incluso saber si es Android, IOS, la versión del SO, etc.

Hay otras formas según como tengas desarrollado tu sitio.

[Información obtenida de ecapy.com](http://ecapy.com/detectar-el-navegador-y-toda-su-informacion-desde-php-o-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

No soy un experto pero se me ocurren dos soluciones, una es utilizando la tecnología **jQuery**, con esta tendrías obtener el ancho de la pantalla, muy similar como lo hacías con el **query** en el **css**, pero ahora con **jQuery**, luego de saber el tamaño de la pantalla usas un `if` o un `switch` como estructura de control para construir diferente tu web en los distintos tamaños.

La otra forma que te podría servir es con **java script** antes de cargar la pagina consultar el tamaño de la pantalla si es de móviles que lo redirija a un sub-dominio que tenga la misma pagina versión móvil, de lo contrario no redirija a ningún lado y permita cargar el contenido de la pagina actual.

Answer (score 0):

Pues el hecho de que establezcas un `display:none` no quiere decir que el elemento no exista pues literalmente traducido, existe mas no es mostrado y por lo tanto, igualmente carga. Recuerda que el HTML es estático y los elementos no son creados por arte de magia, están plasmados en el código. Lo único que te puedo recomendar el usar Javascript, ya que con ellas puedes crear nuevos elementos en el DOM que antes no existían en el código, podrías hacer como una especie de condición que si el medio de visualización es movil, no crea el elemento, de otra manera, crear dicho elemento. Ademas, en vez de usar el `display:none` yo te recomiendo utilizar un framework CSS como materialize o bootstrap, es mucho mas facil ocultar y mostrar elementos utilizando las clases de las mismas

Answer (score 0):

Con `display:none`, simplemente estas diciendo que no se muestre, pero estara ahi su presencia del elemento, una alternativa seria eliminar por completo ese elemento cuando se encuentre en **determinada pantalla(ancho de pantalla)** como indicas con las `@media querys`, te dejo un codigo que elimina elementos mediante `id`.

```js
function eliminarPorId(id) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
    return elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);
}




eliminarPorId("segundoDiv");
```

```css
#primerDiv{
background:red;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
 #segundoDiv{
background:blue;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
.tercerDiv{
background:orange;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="primerDiv"></div>
<div id="segundoDiv"><img src="http://cdn01.ib.infobae.com/adjuntos/162/imagenes/014/014/0014014674.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"></div>

<div class="tercerDiv"></div>
```

Ahora viendo en el *inspector de codigo:* no existe el div con `id=segundoDiv`(porque fue eliminado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si bien se carga aun es **por que no se utilizo algunas condiciones**, una solucion seria hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente, iterar por todos los divs de la pagina.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  if(divs[i].className!="divsNecesarios"){
    var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName(divs[i].className);

while(elemento[0]) {
    elemento[0].parentNode.removeChild(elemento[0]);
}
  
  }
}
```

```css
    #primerDiv{
    background:red;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
    }
     #segundoDiv{
    background:blue;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
    }
    .divsNecesarios{
    background:orange;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="primerDiv" class="noNecesarios"></div>
    <div id="segundoDiv" class="noNecesarios"><img src="http://cdn01.ib.infobae.com/adjuntos/162/imagenes/014/014/0014014674.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" class="cualquiera"> </div>

    <div class="divsNecesarios"></div>
    <div class="divsNecesarios"></div>
```

Comment: Según yo tardaría el sitio en cargarse de igual manera o incluso lo haría tardar más, y bien tendría que saber aun así cuando si ejecutar la función y cuando no

Comment: @JuankGlezz si lo utiliza para pocos elementos?, aun asi es una alternativa a su problema de *los elementos desaparecen pero revisando el Network del inspector veo que se cargan igual*

Comment: por eso dije *tendría que saber aun así cuando si ejecutar la función y cuando no* esto se puede corregir detectando en ancho de pantalla

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. He probado metiendo una imagen en el #segundoDiv y según el inspector descarga la imagen. Está haciendo lo mismo que el display:none...

Comment: @x-rw pero si vas a la pestaña de Network y debajo a Img, fijate que aparece la imagen con un tamaño y tiempo de carga

Comment: @agujex lo que quieres hacer no se si sea posible, por que por defecto te carga todos los elementos html, a ese se aplica css y javascript. por lo tanto siempre se cargara y luego se podra eliminar o hacer algo con esos elementos.

Answer (score 0):

La única forma que veo de realizar lo que deseas es usando este pequeño truco (partiendo del código de @x-rw para no tener que escribir todo desde 0):

```js
function regenerar(id) {
  var media = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)");
  var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    if (media.matches) {
      var srcc = elementos[i].getAttribute("srcc");
      if (srcc !== null) {
        elementos[i].src = srcc;
      }
    } else {
      if (elementos[i].src == "") {
        elementos[i].src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=";
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Todos los navegadores excepto IE < 9 */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", regenerar, false);
```

```css
#primerDiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#segundoDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.tercerDiv {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="primerDiv"></div>
<div id="segundoDiv"><img src="http://cdn01.ib.infobae.com/adjuntos/162/imagenes/014/014/0014014674.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"></div>
<div class="tercerDiv"><img srcc="http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/icons/cc.large.png" alt="Smiley face" height="384" width="384"></div>
```

Registramos una función que será llamada cuando el documento haya sido cargado. En ese momento analizamos todas las imágenes del documento e intercambiamos su atributo `srcc` por el `src` sólo si éste está definido.

No me gusta mucho la solución, pero creo que podría ayudarte a conseguir lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Mientras una etiqueta de `<img>` este en tu código esta sera cargada.

Lo que te sugiero es que cargues por defectos todas tus imagen tengan en su atributo **src** una misma imagen de **1x1 px** y en un atributo data, por ejemplo **data-src** coloques la ruta la verdadera imagen.

Con esto y una vez que cargue el sitio solo cargara una imagen pequeña de **1x1 px** y luego con algo de JavaScript cambiar el atributo **src** por el valor del atributo **data-src** de las imágenes que realmente quieras cargar en el móvil.

Te adjunto un ejemplo con jQuery:

```js
$('img[data-src]:not(.hide-on-movil)').each(function () {
 var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('src', $this.data('src'));
});
```

```css
.hide-on-movil {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://placehold.it/1x1" data-src="http://placehold.it/300?text=Not+show+in+Movil" class="hide-on-movil">

<img src="http://placehold.it/1x1" data-src="http://placehold.it/300?text=Show+in+Movil">
```

Espero te sirva para entender la idea y te sea de utilidad.

Suerte y Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El tema de las imágenes lo resolví usando la etiqueta `picture` con el atributo `srcset`. Luego con javascript para que no carguen otros elementos pesados como videos o iframes . Los elementos los metí en un div con `display:none` para llegar en cierta forma a la solución de la pregunta formulada.

Ejecuten el código en pantalla completa, achiquen la pantalla a menos de 500px, refresquen y se podrá apreciar en el Network del inspector que no se cargan los elementos. El iframe comienza a cargar pero se cancela de inmediato.

```js
screen_resize()

function screen_resize() {
  var h = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
  var w = parseInt(window.innerWidth);

  if (w <= 500) {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.parentNode.removeChild(video);

  }

}
```

```css
div {
  display: none
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  div {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<div>
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/10/21/06/eye-1132531_960_720.jpg" media="(min-width: 500px)" />
    <img srcset="" width="320" height="240" />
  </picture>

  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4">
  </video>

  <iframe width="300" height="180" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qa2SaMbt5xg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</html>
```